# Angular req: HttpRequest<any> not generic

Tags: angular, httprequest

I'm creating a service "error interceptor" but when i try to instantiate a HttpRequest it doesnt allow.

I'm new to Angular and Web App.

Here's my attempt

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpRequest } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                const applicationerror = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                if (applicationerror) {
                    console.log(applicationerror);
                    return throwError(applicationerror);
                }
            }
        })
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't allow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are importing `HttpRequest` from `selenium-webdriver/http` and not from `@angular/common/http`

Remove this:

```
import { HttpRequest } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
```

And add `HttpRequest` like this:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
```